# $REMOTE_ADDR variable in the script not working

Tags: php, php-5.6

I recently converted my PHP 4.0 scripts to PHP 5.6 along with the upgrade of my server from 4.0 to 5.6 as well

However, the `$REMOTE_ADDR` line in the PHP script does not return a value now that the server is running PHP 5.6 and I can't figure this out:

```
$EmailFooter="REFERENCE COMPUTER ADDRESS: ($REMOTE_ADDR)";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Register globals is deprectated (see http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php) you shoud use the superglobal $_SERVER instead, like this

```
$EmailFooter="REFERENCE COMPUTER ADDRESS: ({$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']})";
```